# ServiceControl Beta 7.15 RavenDB Error - Failed to execute indexing function on MessagesViewIndex

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus, service-control-manager

Helpful information to include
Product name:

Version:

Stacktrace:

Description:

I just upgraded ServiceControl from Beta6 to Beta7.15 and I am getting the following error (see at the bottom of the is post) when I start the service and it just seems to hang there.  Note that I deleted the previous database via the following script as outlined in the directions.

```
net stop "Particular ServiceControl"

RD C:\programdata\particular\ServiceControl\localhost-33333 /S

net start "Particular ServiceControl"
```

I also configured the ServiceControl config file using the following settings.  I used the `ServiceControl/Hostname` and `ServiceControl/ExposeRavenDB` setting with Beta 6 with success.  I just added `ExpirationProcessTimerInSeconds` and `HoursToKeepMessagesBeforeExpiring` using the instructions provided.

```
<add key="ServiceControl/Hostname" value="*" />  
<add key="ServiceControl/ExposeRavenDB" value="true" />

<add key="ExpirationProcessTimerInSeconds" value="600" />
<add key="HoursToKeepMessagesBeforeExpiring" value="168" />
```

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
2014-03-28 15:49:13.5041|Warn|Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.Indexing|Failed to execute indexing function on MessagesViewIndex on FailedMessages/f027b8ef-2be5-7403-820f-4c358ddecba9
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'
    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int32 )
    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
    at Index_MessagesViewIndex.<.ctor>b__5e(Object message)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at Raven.Database.Indexing.RobustEnumerator.MoveNext(IEnumerator en, StatefulEnumerableWrapper`1 innerEnumerator) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v2.5-New\Raven.Database\Indexing\RobustEnumerator.cs:line 91
```

Comment: Note that I tried removing the ExpirationProcessTimerInSeconds and HoursToKeepMessagesBeforeExpiring app settings and I still go the same error.  Correction, these are actually warnings, but are highly suspect.

Comment: I noticed that I also had a database under C:\programdata\particular\ServiceControl\%-33333 and it appears to be using this one which contains old messages which I assume are not backward compatible with the index, hence why we were instructed to delete the existing ravendb database.  My question now would be - why did I have two versions %-33333 and localhost-33333.

Comment: I have a hunch that the instructions are wrong. Can you try to uninstall servicecontrol. Make sure that the folder is empty. Install the new version. Make sure the is only one folder there?